# SAS Proc Transpose data 4

Tags: sas, transpose

In SAS I have something like this...

```
ID  survey  Q1  q1_2  Q2  q2_2 Q3  q3_2
1     1      1        0        1    
1     2          0         1        1
2     2          1         1        0
```

I’m not sure if transposing is the right way to go but I’d like to get something like this.

```
ID  survey  Q Response
1    1      1   1 
            2   0
            3   1
     2      1   0
            2   1
            3   1
2    2      1   1
            2   1
            3   0
```

Where Q1 and Q1_2 are the same question presented in two different surveys given over time

Comment: What have you tried? I would suggest PROC TRANSPOSE for starters and then cleaning up the data after the fact based on the Question Number/Value in the transposed table.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is coalesce function.

> ```
>  proc sql;
>    select id, 
>           survey,  
>            coalesce(Q1,q1_2) as q1,
>            coalesce(Q2,q2_2) as q2,
>            coalesce(Q3,q3_2) as q3
>     from yourtable;
>     quit;
> ```

Comment: Thanks Kiran. I don’t have the data with me, So, after thinking some more I had to edit the question. But thank you for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL UNION CORR to append Survey 1 & Survey 2 ... & Survey N data.
Code:

```
/*Append Survery 1 & Suervey 2 data to each other*/
proc sql;
create table want as 
select 
    id, survey, q1, q2, q3 
    from have
    where survey=1
union corr
select
    id, survey, 
    q1_2 as q1, 
    q2_2 as q2, 
    q3_2 as q3
    from have
    where survey=2
;
quit;
```

Output:

```
ID=1 survey=1 Q1=1 Q2=0 Q3=1 
ID=1 survey=2 Q1=0 Q2=1 Q3=1 
ID=2 survey=2 Q1=1 Q2=1 Q3=0
```

Comment: Performance wise Kiran's answer is better with using Coalesce. so I'll upvote his answer.